# Make a footer div fill 100% width of browser

Tags: html, css, footer, viewport-units

I have this problem: [Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fngZt.jpg)

the top bar always fills the width of browser (it is bootstrap). The bottom however does not. If set to 100vw it gives it a 9600px length and I end up with a white bar on the left that increases as the viewer width increases. 
Giving it the same CSS as the top bar makes it always stay on view, no matter where you are on the page.

My body is fixed at 1440px width.

I want the bottom bar to be like the top bar, but be in view only when you scroll at the bottom.

Bottom bar code:

```
<div class="content">
<footer id="myFooter">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <h5>Get started</h5>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <h5>About us</h5>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Company Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <h5>Support</h5>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Help desk</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 info">
                <h5>Information</h5>
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam consectetur aliquet aliquet. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second-bar">
       <div class="container">
            <h2 class="logo"><a href="#"> LOGO </a></h2>
            <div class="social-icons">
                <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="google"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

This footer is a free sample that I use because the table on my previews one would always collapse when viewed in browser.

And yes. I AM NOOB! xD

```
.content {
background-color: #FAEBD7;}
```

Comment: Have you tried moving your footer HTML outside of the wrapper that has a fixed width?

Comment: cant see anything wrong here. either post the whole issue, or at least those two parts that doesn't work as expected in one HTML snippet. better yet make a jsfiddle. https://www.bootply.com/TqJP4aYqLQ#

Comment: Remove `<div class="container">` from `<div class="second-bar">`

Comment: I removed the fixed width from the body (Noobity Level: Over the Scale) and I created a Wrapper instead, leaving the footer out of it.
A little fiddling with CSS and the Footer fits perfectly! I also undeformed my table by mere luck, trial and error. And with some search on this website I solved some other issues :)

<3<3<3 THANK YOU ALL FOR THE REPLIES !!! <3<3<3

You have just helped me far more than you might anticipate!

Answer (score 0):

try to get footer outside of any other div...

```
<body>
  <nav>menu...</nav>
  <div>some content...<div>
  <footer>footer content..</footer>
</body>
```

i guess "container" class give some margin or padding on div (that's why footer doesn't have width of 100%), put footer outside or remove container class from div...